# Use old NuGet package with modern Visual Studio toolset

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nuget, version

I am tinkering with NuGet package manager in C++ projects and encountered a problem. In my VS 2017 RC (which has Platform Toolset v.141) project I've added two packages - GLEW and GLFW specifically. I successfully included corresponding headers, but couldn't link my project - apparently the packages weren't built for VS 2017.

In `packages/<package>/build/native/lib` there are several `v###` subfolders: `v100, v110` for GLEW and `v100, v110, v120, v140` for GLFW. From what I understand, these contain binaries compiled against corresponding VS toolsets. If I change platform toolset for my project from `v141` to `v140` (I have VS 2015 also installed), GLFW linking errors disappear (since VS founds the corresponding binaries from GLFW package), but GLEW still doesn't link - and neither I have the `v110` toolset, nor I want to downgrade there.

Is there a way to link an older NuGet C++ package to a project with modern platform toolset? I'm fine with building the package from source if it is possible somehow - as long as it stays a nuget package that gets managed automatically to some point.

Answer (score 1):

We could not link an older NuGet C++ package to a project with modern platform toolset.

Visual Studio supports multiple platform toolsets, but the modern platform toolsets are not backward compatible. So the v100, v110 for GLEW will generate link error when using the platform toolset v140 in VS 2015.

The best way to use v100,v110 for GLEW in Visual Studio 2015 is installing the v110 toolset and use it to maintain binary-compatible legacy code.

For the detail information about configuring programs for old platform, please refer to:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851139.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no package that includes v141 PlatformToolset. You can always force linking the v140 targeted binaries against your v141 project by editing the included config in packages\googletest.1.8.0.0\build\native\googletest.targets:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Label="Win32 and v140 and Release" Condition="'$(Platform.ToLower())' == 'win32' And '$(PlatformToolset.ToLower())' == 'v140' And ( $(Configuration.ToLower().IndexOf('debug')) == -1 )">
```

to

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Label="Win32 and v140 and Release" Condition="'$(Platform.ToLower())' == 'win32' And '$(PlatformToolset.ToLower())' == 'v141' And ( $(Configuration.ToLower().IndexOf('debug')) == -1 )">
```

But yout milage might vary.